# How to normalize this database table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, database-schema, database-normalization

I'm new to SQL. I am currently using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I was hoping that you guys can check if the tables are normalized because I always had the assumption that my work has its flaws or I'm just being paranoid.

If the tables are not normalized please tell which one and why is it wrong. So far these are the tables that I got in 3NF and as much as possible if it can reach bcnf. I just need to confirm that it is in a normalized form or not, don't need the real answer :D

This is from a large table PurchaseOrder and I've normalized it through 3NF, I got 5 tables as a result:

[image]

This is from a large table Material Received and I've also normalized it through 3NF, I got 5 tables as a result:

[image]

Comment: What functional dependencies did you use to come up with this?

Comment: If you want us to check your work you have to show & justify what you did. All we can do is see if the answer you give is a possible answer. What is your justification? Please read the comments on the last 10 database-normalization questions. Please read [ask] including about homework. PS You can always put a table into BCNF. You just can't always preserve functional dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The tables are normalized in 3rd order form. There are no repeating columns and every column (in every table) is dependent on the primary key and only on the primary key. The final test is to see if you can create sql statements that will provide usable results such as to generate a list of all po's for a given date and include how much income was generated.

Comment: *" every column ... is dependent on the primary key and only on the primary key"*  You probably meant to say that every column is dependent on *every* candidate key.